# Retrieve Html table data after invoking button click from WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

While trying following code i am getting  null reference error

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textbox1").InnerText = "sometext";
  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textbox2").InnerText = "sometext";  
  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Button1").InvokeMember("click");
  object tb = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Table1").All;
}
```

without 4th line my code is working fine. But added 4th line i am getting error.

Actually I want save the table generated after button1 clicked.
There is no table1 on the previous page i.e before button clicked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Document property of your WebBrowser is null because the browser has not loaded the page yet. You need to handle the DocumentCompleted event of the WebBrowser and access the HTML code in it.

```
private void webbrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // access HTML here
}
```

Comment: I tried this but webbrowser_DocumentCompleted() method never firing

Comment: you need to add `webbrowser.DocumentCompleted += webbrowser_DocumentCompleted;` in the constructor of your form to handle the event.

Comment: Or maybe there is no element with `Table1` as `id` in the document.

Comment: Or maybe there is no element with `Table1` as `id` in the document.

Comment: If the GetElementById returns null, it's because the id was not found. Check the value of `webbrowser.Document.Body.OuterHtml` to view all the HTML and to be sure the id `Table1` is there.

Comment: Table1 is there but i need to login before that code runs. When first open login page table1 is not there. Now how to skip first 2 document completed events or if webBrowser1 doesnot have table1 do nothing.                how could i store that table in a datatable for further processing

Comment: You could just add a condition like this: `HtmlElement table1 = webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("Table1");
if (table1 != null)
    {// do something}`

Answer (score 0):

Use something as below. I think it will work.

```
        HtmlElement hleGetData = (HtmlElement)hdoc.GetElementById("getButton");
        hleGetData.InvokeMember("click");
        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        };

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```